# Character vector doesn't order by specified order in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following vector:

```
lev <- c("apple", "key lime", "boston creme", "blueberry", "cherry", "pumpkin", "strawberry")
```

It's a level vector.

I have a vector:

```
pies$flavor
 [1] cherry       cherry       cherry       cherry       cherry      
 [6] cherry       cherry       cherry       cherry       cherry      
[11] cherry       cherry       cherry       key lime     key lime    
[16] key lime     key lime     key lime     key lime     key lime    
[21] key lime     key lime     key lime     key lime     key lime    
[26] key lime     key lime     key lime     key lime     boston creme
[31] boston creme boston creme boston creme boston creme boston creme
[36] boston creme boston creme boston creme boston creme boston creme
[41] boston creme boston creme boston creme boston creme strawberry  
[46] strawberry   strawberry   strawberry   strawberry   strawberry  
[51] strawberry   strawberry   strawberry   strawberry   strawberry  
[56] blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    blueberry   
[61] blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    blueberry   
[66] blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    blueberry    apple       
[71] apple        apple        apple        apple        apple       
[76] apple        apple        apple        apple        apple       
[81] apple        apple        apple        apple        apple       
[86] apple        pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin     
[91] pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin     
[96] pumpkin      pumpkin      pumpkin
```

Now I want reorder the levels of flavor so that they're in descending order by count.

What I did is `lev[order(table(pies$flavor), decreasing = T)]`
but the actual output is wrong:

```
lev[order(table(pies$flavor), decreasing = T)]
[1] "apple"        "cherry"       "boston creme" "key lime"     "blueberry"   
[6] "pumpkin"      "strawberry"
```

because the actual order by count:

```
order(table(pies$flavor), decreasing = T)
[1] 1 5 3 2 4 6 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "level vector". Provided I understood you correctly you want to use ordered `lev` as the `levels` of a `factor` variable. Try `pies$flavour <- factor(pies$flavour, levels = sort(lev, decreasing = TRUE))`. Or if this is about sorting the *table* you can do a simple `sort(table(pies$flavour), decreasing = T)`.

Comment: No, I need it to be sorted in descending order by their count. If level apple = 20 and level cherry = 11 then apple will come before cherry.

Comment: I just edited my comment; does `sort(table(pies$flavour), decreasing = T)` do want you want? This sorts the table by decreasing count.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a lot, so what was wrong with my positioning?

Comment: `table` internally converts to `factor`; it seems that the order of `levels` is not the same as `lev`. You can get around this by *explicitly* setting the `factor` levels: `lev[order(table(factor(pies$flavour, levels = lev)), decreasing = T)]`; you can check that the order will be the same as in `sort(table(pies$flavour), decreasing = T)`.